# How to remove a div in JavaScript? How to add input fields in the same div

Tags: javascript, field

I want to dynamically add/remove a div.
I've managed to get the add button working with this code:

```
$('#addSelector').live('click', function() {
$('<div id=' + c + ' class="title">...<input type="button" id="remSelector'+ c +'" value="Remove Selector"></div>').appendTo(addDivSelector);
c++;
```

So it basically adds the remove button, and I want it to delete it's div (for example remSelector5 removes the div with the id 5.

Another problem I have with this code:
I've managed to dynamically add/remove input fields with this code:

```
var i = $('#addinput p').size() + 1;
var addDiv = $('#addinput');
$('#addNew').live('click', function() {
$('<p> ... <input type="text" name="value' + i + '" placeholder="Value"/>&nbsp <input type="button" id="remNew" value="Remove Operator"/></p>').appendTo(addDiv);
i++;
```

The first code from this post generates the second code (except the var declarations). When I press the button with the id "addNew" on the second or third div for example, it generates a new field in the first div. I want it to generate a new input field in the same div, but I can't manage to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardly understand your needs, but that's what i can offer:

```
    var id = 0,
    textId = 0;

$("#magicButton").on("click", function () {
    id++;
    var content = 
        '<div id="someDiv_' + id + '" class="title">' +
    '<input type="button" data-id="' + id + '" value="remove" class="removeButton"/>' +
    '<input type="button" data-id="' + id + '" value="addText" class="addText"/>' + 
    '</div>';
    $("#someContainer").append(content);
    //bind event handlers:
    $(".removeButton").off("click").on("click", removeDiv);
    $(".addText").off("click").on("click", addText);

});

function removeDiv() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#someDiv_" + id).remove();
}

function addText() {
    textId++;
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var content = '<div id="txtContainer_' + textId + '"><input type="text" value="some text"/><input type="button" value="X" data-textid="' + textId + '" class="removeText"/></div>';
    $("#someDiv_" + id).append(content);
    $(".removeText").off("click").on("click", removeText);
}

function removeText() {
    var textId = $(this).data("textid");
    $("#txtContainer_" + textId).remove();
}
```

Check it at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eqVWz/1/)

That codez actually demonstrate how to wotk with dynamic elements on a page and how to get rid of `.live()` which isn't good to use

Comment: This is 70% what I want to do. If I use this and the script from the comment above, I can do what I want. Thank you!

Comment: I needed to dynamically add/remove divs (what you did here for me) and dynamically add/remove input from each div. I think I can do that, as I said, using your script and inser's script. I will try.

Comment: Yes, I will accept your answer because it's the most relevant. Can you, please, help me to dynamically add/remove fields in every div?

Comment: code works fine in jsFiddle, but I can't get it working on the server. Do you have any ideea why?

Comment: Check markup, ids, classes, jquery version (m.b. you use very old one?)

Comment: I'm using XAMPP v3.1.0. I don't get it... It works just fine on jsFiddle, but it's not working when I open it in my browser. It only displays the "Click me!" button from my php file. I'm using <script src="js/functions.js"></script> to include my js file. Is anything wrong with this? I don't get it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would solve your first problem:

```
$('#addSelector').live('click', function() {
    $('<div id=' + c + ' class="title">...<input type="button" class="removeButton" id="remSelector'+ c +'" value="Remove Selector"></div>').appendTo(addDivSelector);
    c++;
});

addDivSelector.find("input.removeButton").live("click", function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This requires addDivSelector to be a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to see something like this:

```
$('.add-row').click(function() {
    var input = $('<input type="text" />');
    var btn = $('<input type="button" value="x" />');

    btn.click(function() {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });

    var div = $('<div />');
    div.append(input).append(btn);    

    $('.container').append(div);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/inser/LHjx4/

Comment: I can already do that, I want to do that and add containers too, so I can add and remove an input field in every container. I can add container with the first code I've posted, but when I try to add an input field from the second container (div) it adds one in the first container.